# "ld: library not found for -lSystem" when installing homebrew ruby on Big Sur

Tags: ruby, macos, homebrew, rbenv

Installing OS11 Big Sur made it so my ruby installation no longer works, so I'm trying to reinstall it. I've installed `rbenv` from the instructions [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos), and the `rbenv-doctor` script runs indicating no problems. But when I try to run `rbenv install 2.7.2` I get an error related to my compiler setup:

```
% rbenv install 2.7.2
Downloading ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2...
-> https://cache.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/2.7/ruby-2.7.2.tar.bz2
Installing ruby-2.7.2...
ruby-build: using readline from homebrew

BUILD FAILED (macOS 11.0.1 using ruby-build 20201005)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /var/folders/yn/wzkl_t8567l9pvwhp0wsm40w0000gn/T/ruby-build.20201121103616.80606.FFBFEn
Results logged to /var/folders/yn/wzkl_t8567l9pvwhp0wsm40w0000gn/T/ruby-build.20201121103616.80606.log

Last 10 log lines:
tool/config.guess already exists
tool/config.sub already exists
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/var/folders/yn/wzkl_t8567l9pvwhp0wsm40w0000gn/T/ruby-build.20201121103616.80606.FFBFEn/ruby-2.7.2':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

The corresponding `config.log` is quite long, of course, but relevant lines are:

```
configure:3017: checking for ruby
configure:3035: found /usr/bin/ruby
configure:3048: result: /usr/bin/ruby
configure:3121: checking build system type
configure:3135: result: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
configure:3223: checking host system type
configure:3236: result: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
configure:3256: checking target system type
configure:3269: result: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
configure:4016: checking for C compiler version
configure:4025: clang --version >&5
clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/clang6/bin
configure:4036: $? = 0
configure:4025: clang -v >&5
clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/clang6/bin
configure:4036: $? = 0
configure:4025: clang -V >&5
clang-6.0: error: argument to '-V' is missing (expected 1 value)
clang-6.0: error: no input files
configure:4036: $? = 1
configure:4025: clang -qversion >&5
clang-6.0: error: unknown argument: '-qversion'
clang-6.0: error: no input files
configure:4036: $? = 1
configure:4056: checking whether the C compiler works
configure:4078: clang  -I/Users/richard/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/include -I/usr/local/opt/readline/include -L/Users/richard/.rbenv/versions/2.7.2/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib conftest.c  >&5
ld: library not found for -lSystem
clang-6.0: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
configure:4082: $? = 1
configure:4120: result: no
configure: failed program was:
| /* confdefs.h */
| #define PACKAGE_NAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
| #define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
| #define PACKAGE_STRING ""
| #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
| #define PACKAGE_URL ""
| /* end confdefs.h.  */
| 
| int
| main ()
| {
| 
|   ;
|   return 0;
| }
configure:4125: error: in `/var/folders/yn/wzkl_t8567l9pvwhp0wsm40w0000gn/T/ruby-build.20201121101556.78734.11rqwy/ruby-2.7.2':
configure:4127: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

The (main?) problem appears to be the error:

```
ld: library not found for -lSystem
```

...but the errors before it seem to imply that the configure script doesn't understand the command line options...?

Here are some relevant details about my setup:

XCode command line tools:

```
% pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | grep version
version: 12.2.0.0.1.1604076827
```

gcc:

```
% which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
```

```
% gcc -v
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.27)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin
```

clang:

```
% which clang
/usr/local/clang6/bin/clang
```

```
% clang -v
clang version 6.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.1.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/clang6/bin
```

I also have the following in my `.zprofile`, in order to fix the problem that it wasn't finding the necessary header files before:

```
export CPATH="/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include"
```

Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: hitting this as well.

Comment: Hi @richarddmorey, have you managed to fix the problem?

Comment: @MartinFink nope...going to bounty this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem appears to be that you're using `clang6` (probably from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/tools/) instead of the version of `clang` that ships with the Xcode Command Line Tools. You need Apple's version of `clang`.

Verify that you have installed the CLT with `sudo xcode-select --install`. Once they're installed verify that `/usr/bin/clang -v` returns something like `Apple clang version 12`. Now modify your `$PATH` and retry:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
rbenv install 2.7.2
```

Or use whatever other shell trick you prefer to get the Apple version of `clang` to be used by rbenv, then retry the installation.

Comment: Just tried this and indeed I make progress, but now I see "compile.c:9859:63: error: use of undeclared identifier 'RUBY_FUNCTION_NAME_STRING'". Argh!

Comment: Then [this](https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build/issues/1431) will probably help.

Comment: Tried that first; no effect, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If using [rvm](https://rvm.io/) a possibility, I was able to successfully install `2.7.2` version on **MacOS Big Sur**

Installation Command output is captured here https://gist.github.com/gowtham1984/ba04219aa03dd29e5d44d48164c15c7a